# "Reverse" Reed-Solomon error correction, given prefix of input

Tags: hash

I have a string $S$ of length (say) 34, that I know the first (say) 24 bytes of, but not the last 10. I also have the 10-byte error correcting code $RS_{44,34}(S)$ in full. Do I have any hope of recovering $S$?

The amount of information of $S$ that I'm missing far exceeds the theoretical guarantee of Reed-Solomon (which I think in this case is 3 bytes), but at the same time, there's $2^{80}$ possible values for the unknown portion of $S$, and also $2^{80}$ possible outputs for the error correction. If we were to iterate over all possible values for the unknown portion of $S$, I would naively expect approximately 1 of them to match the error correction. But $2^{80}$ is too much to brute force.

Are there any techniques that could recover (or at least reduce the state space for) an input, given its Reed-Solomon EC? Is there any reason to think one way or the other that RS is cryptographically secure in this sense?

For background, the "real world" application here is that I have a QR code (version 2, L-level EC) where I don't have the main data bits, but I do have the EC bits. I know that the data is a URL on a particular domain, thus the prefix.

Answer (score 1):

> Are there any techniques that could recover (or at least reduce the state space for) an input, given its Reed-Solomon EC?

You are in luck - Reed-Solomon is a linear code, that is, the error correcting section is a linear function of the input, and in fact, by fixing all but 10 bytes of the input, it is a bijection.

What this means is that you can efficiently reconstruct the missing 10 bytes of the input; Gaussian elimination would work, and while there are likely to be more efficient algorithms available, Gaussian elimination would take approximately $10^3$ operations, and so that could be efficient enough.

Answer (score 0):

Not all codes have the nice property that RS codes have, which is that every $k$ symbols are an information set which can be used to reconstruct the original codeword.

There are efficient *erasure decoders* out there. Erasure means that some symbols are unknown, not just errored.

For example, this [recent paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0901.1886.pdf) presents an efficient decoding algorithm for RS codes over the finite field with $q$ elements, $\mathbb{F}_q$ with $q=2^m,$ in $O(q \log_q q^2)$ time. It uses walsh transforms to do Lagrange interpolation.